# UITableView custom separator, hidding when selecting

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview

I've got quick question. I've got a `UITableViewController` with custom cells which have custom separator (as a `UIImageView` that is a subview of `cell.contentView`). Now when I'm selecting a cell I want to hide my separator so it would not be visible on my highlighted background.

I was trying to use such constructions as:

```
self.separatorImageViewTop.frame = CGRectMake(-240, 0, 120, 2);        

self.separatorImageViewTop.hidden = YES;

self.separatorImageViewTop.alpha = 0;

[self.separatorImageViewTop.frame removeFromSuperview]
```

Each of this ways is working but each of them is making a blinking effect on custom separator when cell is selected. How can I avoid this blinking effect?

My code is invoked from:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but I've tried to use with:

```
-(NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

hoping that actuall highlighting of a cell would occur after `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, but the result are the same - still blinking effect of a disapearing`UIImageView`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try override this method in your custom cell:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```